# Unable to get params from current url?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am new to react.js. I am unable to get params from the current URL.

Here is the function I use:

```
var Base_URL = window.location.href;
```

Now I want to parse the params of current URL that looks like this:  `url=xyz&email=xyz`. How can I achieve this with React. I perfectly get all values while using node.js.

Comment: `const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search)` - then you can do e.g. `for (const [key, value] of params.entries()) console.log(\`${key} = ${value}\`)` or `console.log(params.get('email'))`. See docs for [`Location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location) and [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams).

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `react-router-dom` package's useLocation hook.

```
    const function useSearchQuery() {
      const { search } = useLocation();
      return useMemo(() => new URLSearchParams(search), [search]);
    }
```

Then call the function and get the params you want

```
    const query = useSearchQuery();
    email = query.get('email')
```